# How can i SendMessage to Internet Explorer 9 with WinAPI

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, winapi, win32-process

environment:
windows 7
visual studio 2010 c++ Win32 API
Internet Explorer 9
OpenGL

project objective:
texturing internet explorer9's screen realtime on a 3d-Plane(GL_QUADS). and mouse picking on 3d-plane, the click message with relative-mouse position is posted real internet explorer 9.
the objectvie is 'control other program with 3d texturing and mouse action on my application'

code:

```
HWND target;

//...
//in winmain
target = ::FindWindow("IEFrame",NULL);
glutMouseFunc(MouseEvent);
//...


//in MouseEvent
void MouseEvent(int iButton, int iState, int x, int y)
{
    if(iState == GLUT_DOWN)
    {
        if(iButton == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON)
        {
             POINT p;
             p.x = x; p.y = y;
             POINT pOut = PickWithPlane(target,p);
             //I don't explain this function. cuz it has very long codes and so complicated and don't important. 
             //it is a simply transform point from my application's Client picking point 'p' to target application(=HWND target)'s relative picking point.

             //send a click message to target. but this SendMessage don't work.
             SendMessage(target, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, MK_LBUTTON, MAKELPARAM(pOut.x, POut.y);
        }
    }
}
```

i used **PostMessage** insted of **SendMessage**, but the result is same.
the internet explore don't send any reaction.

i watch using Microsoft Spy++ message window.

```
// on real-click IE9's window any point
<10972> 000C0F82 S WM_PARENTNOTIFY fwEvent: WM_LBUTTONDOWN xPos:475 yPos:700
<10973> 000C0F82 R WM_PARENTNOTIFY
<10974> 000C0F82 S WM_MOUSEACTIVATE hwndTopLevel:000C0F82 nHittest:HTCLIENT uMsg:WM_LBUTTONDOWN
<10975> 000C0F82 R WM_MOUSEACTIVATE fuActivate:MA_ACTIVATE
<10976> 000C0F82 S WM_SETCURSOR hwnd:00231438 nHittest:HTCLIENT wMouseMsg:WM_LBUTTONDOWN
<10977> 000C0F82 R WM_SETCURSOR fHaltProcessing:False
//mouseup
<10978> 000C0F82 S WM_SETCURSOR hwnd:00231438 nHittest:HTCLIENT wMouseMsg:WM_MOUSEMOVE
<10979> 000C0F82 R WM_SETCURSOR fhaltProcessing:False
```

and send message using my application code is next:

```
// on my application's messge
<13106> 000C0F82 S WM_LBUTTONDOWN fwKeys:MK_LBUTTON xPos:1231 yPos:289
<13107> 000C0F82 R WM_LUBTTONDOWN
```

i guess some more message send. but i don't know what message can do this.
who knows solution of it?
and who knows controlling general application using this way?

help me!

Answer (score 2):

Some programs don't submit to input faking with `PostMessage` or `SendMessage`. Instead you should fake input with [`SendInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310.aspx). You may find that a higher level approach using UI Automation is easier than faking input.